# CPU Doesn't Go Below 5.5 watts on idle

Tags: windows-10, cpu, power, idle

I recently updated my laptop  (i7-6700HQ, 8gb ram) from Windows home 1703 to Windows Pro 2004 and now on idle my CPU will rest at 5.5 watts and temperatures mid/high 40s. On Windows 1703 it would be idle at 0.3 watts and low/mid 30s.

Now the thing is, on this 2004 version there are two instances where the cpu had been idle at 0.3 watts but on reboot it went back to 5.5 watts. I don't know if it's a (hidden) process or something..

I've tried adjusting the power plans, stopping/suspending processes and underclocking with Throttlestop but to no avail.
The Task Manager shows Cpu 0-1%, 26% Memory and Disk 0% but cpu can't go below 5.5 watts. I appreciate any help with this.

My Specs:
Dell Inspiron 7559
Intel Core i7 6700hq
8gb ram
2TB hdd
Windows Pro 2004 build 19041

Comment: I'd suspect your original reading of 0.3W was reading wrongly in whatever software you were using. 0.3W sounds far too low to me.

Comment: @Mokubai It's actually correct (used Coretemp and Throttlestop), and it seems it goes from 0.3 to 5.5 immediately I open the Start menu.

Comment: Unplug external power and let the PC run for an hour or so. Double-click the battery icon in the taskbar. Click on *Battery settings*.  Check *Battery usage per app* to find the energy hogs that might not show in *Task Manager*, and some apps can even be turned off on that CPL.

Comment: @DrMoishepippik the cause seems to be the Start menu. When booted up the  cpu idles at 0.3 watts after doing anything except opening the Start menu, then it idles on 5.5 watts. If I unplug the charger it idles at 0.2 then goes back to 5.5 when I plug it.